# Trouble removing Google Cloud DNS record using gcloud on command line

Tags: dns, gcloud

I have the following DNS zone configured in Google Cloud DNS:

Zone:  test1

Record:

```
abc.test1.com.    CNAME 300 xyz.test1.com.
```

Using gcloud on the command line I can list and obtain information just fine.

However, for some reason (and I had this working some time ago) I can no longer remove (delete) a zone record using these commands:

```
gcloud dns record-sets transaction start --zone=test1
gcloud dns record-sets transaction remove "abc.test1.com." --zone=test1 --name="xyz.test1.com." --type=CNAME --ttl=300
```

...at this point it fails with an error (so I cannot execute the transaction):

```
ERROR: (gcloud.dns.record-sets.transaction.remove) Record to be removed does not exist
```

Yet I know the record is there, which I can confirm with:

```
gcloud dns record-sets list -z test1
```

which displays:

```
abc.test1.com.          CNAME  300      xyz.test1.com.
```

I'd appreciate any pointers.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me you are getting confused between DNS record name and DNS record value.
For the example that you have put up in your question, your CNAME record name is "abc.test1.com." and record value is "xyz.test1.com.".
So in order to delete this record using gcloud, your command should be

gcloud dns record-sets transaction start --zone=test1

gcloud dns record-sets transaction remove **"xyz.test1.com."** --zone=test1 **--name="abc.test1.com."** --type=CNAME --ttl=300

gcloud dns record-sets transaction execute --zone=test1

Try it. This should work. Hope it helps!

Comment: Correct, thanks.  I realized this a few days ago too.